# In-App-Purchase - Restore Purchase does not work?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

In my application, the users can buy PRO membership to unlock stuff.

Here is the view controllers code where the user buy PRO membership:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class UpgradePROViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    @IBOutlet weak var upgradeButton: UIButton!

    var ApplicationLoadTime = NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("isPRO")
    var product_id: NSString?;
    let loadedValue = NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("isPRO")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var ApplicationLoadTimeUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if (ApplicationLoadTimeUserDefault.valueForKey("isPRO") != nil){
            ApplicationLoadTime = ApplicationLoadTimeUserDefault.valueForKey("isPRO") as! NSInteger!
        }

        upgradeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        upgradeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        upgradeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        upgradeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        upgradeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.35).CGColor
        upgradeButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.1, alpha: 0.85).CGColor

        product_id = "com.myself.MyApp.GetPRO";

        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func upgradeButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        buyConsumable()
    }

    @IBAction func restoreButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
            println("Purchased Restored");
        }
    }

    func buyConsumable(){
        println("About to fetch the products");
        // We check that we are allow to make the purchase.
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
            var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
            println("Fething Products");
        }else{
            println("can't make purchases");
        }
    }

    // Helper Methods

    func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
        println("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
        var payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);
    }


    // Delegate Methods for IAP

    func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        println("got the request from Apple")
        var count : Int = response.products.count
        if (count>0) {
            var validProducts = response.products
            var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as! SKProduct
            if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
                println(validProduct.localizedTitle)
                println(validProduct.localizedDescription)
                println(validProduct.price)
                buyProduct(validProduct);
            } else {
                println(validProduct.productIdentifier)
            }
        } else {
            println("nothing")
        }
    }


    func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("La vaina fallo");
    }

    func unlockProFeatures(){
        ApplicationLoadTime = 1

        NSString(format: "isPRO", "%i", 1)

        var ApplicationLoadTimeUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        ApplicationLoadTimeUserDefault.setValue(ApplicationLoadTime, forKey: "isPRO")
        ApplicationLoadTimeUserDefault.synchronize()
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)    {
        println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    println("Product Purchased");
                    unlockProFeatures()
                    break;
                case .Failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    println("Purchased Failed");
                    break;
                case .Restored:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                    println("Purchased Restored");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow, it looks like the restore purchase does not work.. I am testing using sandbox users. Does anybody has any suggestions what to do? It works all fine to buy the items, but when I try to restore the purchase with the same user that has purchased the item, it does not work. Anything wrong in my code, or anything you would do different?